# Hide text before a button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I managed to make a small slide function on a button which can be seen here: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uj47sgLj/1/)

The only problem I have, is that the text is shown from the start now. The text should be hidden until you click the button. Can anybody give me a hint on how to solve that?

**html**

```
 <h3>
  This text should be hidden before you click the button
</h3>
<button>Toggle Me</button>
```

**JS**

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "h3" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hide your H3 at the beginning, with a style-attribute.

```
<h3 style="display: none">his text should be hidden before you click the button</h3>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uj47sgLj/3/

Comment: Technically correct, I'd suggest using a class rather than inline css though.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily apply an inline style attribute (using `display: none`) on your `<h3>` element to hide it:

```
<h3 style='display: none'>
  This text should be hidden before you click the button
</h3>
```

If you were planning on using this for multiple elements, a better approach would be to define a CSS class that would handle hiding it and then applying that class to the element:

```
<style>
    .hidden { display: none; }
</style>
<h3 class='hidden'>
  This text should be hidden before you click the button
</h3>
```

**Example**

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("h3").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 style='display: none'>
  This text should be hidden before you click the button
</h3>
<button>Toggle Me</button>
```

Comment: Ah okay simple solution, thank you :-) I can first accept your answer in 15 minutes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a `visibility: hidden;` property as the value of the `style` attribute of the `<h3>` element in your HTML.

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "h3" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
  h3Text[0].style.visibility = "visible";
});
// NEW CODE
const h3Text = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
```

```css
h3 {
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

 <h3 style="visibility: hidden;">
  This text should be hidden before you click the button
</h3>

<button>Toggle Me</button>
```

Hang on, that's not right.

Try this:

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "h3" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
  h3[0].style.display = "block";
});
// more code
var h3 = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
```

```css
h3 {
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

 <h3 style="DISPLAY: NONE;">
  This text should be hidden before you click the button
</h3>

<button>Toggle Me</button>
```